# I got two different results for the current in one branch, what is wrong with my KVL equations?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

The two circuits are equivalent.

Using Kirchoff Voltage Law.(KVL)

For Loop1, I have: $$12+3000i_1+2000(i_1+1)=0$$.
For Loop2, I have: $$5000i_2+2000(i_2-1)=0$$.

Now, there are two ways to find the current in the middle branch,i3. i3=i1+1=i2-1. But the i3 I got using these two ways are not equal. i1=-0.4024A, and i2=0.286A.(Calculated from the above two equations).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQUEt6-9vU0

Comment: Is that really one amp through a 2k resistor? That's the elephant in the room, so to speak. ;)

Comment: NO, not 1amp, but i3=i1+1=i2-1.

Comment: Looks like a 1A current source to me. Is it? If so, it will drive 1A through that 2k resistor -- no matter what it takes to do it. (Which is why the 2k resistor doesn't matter, by the way.)

Comment: So it is 1amp? Really. Does current source really have infintite resisitance?

Comment: Yes, I3 = 1A because you have a current source in series with 2k resistor.  Do you not know what current source is?

Comment: Nice video G36.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've struggled long enough on this. Let's follow your own guidance, but we need to make a small modification in order to make it work out.

But first a note:

- You should use the *included* schematic editor. A picture of pencil drawings is nice, but the editor makes it absolutely clear for anyone to read and it also makes it easy to number things on the schematic (it does it for you.) I'd have appreciated the addition, anyway. I mention this because you might want to consider the time of those from whom you ask for help. (I will draw it up using the schematic editor, consuming time you should have spent instead of me.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUVMk8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've also taken the time to also note the two unknown node voltages on the schematic: \$V_X\$ and \$V_Y\$. There is a reason for this, which will become a little clearer as I develop the equations. I've also labeled your current source as \$I_3\$, just for clarity's sake (because of \$I_1\$ and \$I_2\$, which are your two branch currents.)

---

So what are the equations from this??

$$\begin{align*}
0\:\textrm{V} + 12\:\textrm{V} + I_1\cdot R_1 +\left(I_1-I_2\right)\cdot R_2-V_Y&=0\:\textrm{V}\label{loop1}\tag{Loop $I_1$}\\\\
0\:\textrm{V} +V_Y+\left(I_2-I_1\right)\cdot R_2 + I_2\cdot R_3 &=0\:\textrm{V}\label{loop2}\tag{Loop $I_2$}\\\\
\left(I_3=\right)I_1-I_2&=1\:\textrm{A}\label{given}\tag{Given}
\end{align*}$$

That's three equations and three unknowns. (Note that \$V_X\$ isn't really necessary here, since you are doing this via a branch current method.)

---

What did I do differently? Well, you have no given information at all about the voltage across the current source. It will have to "adjust itself" to generate whatever voltage is necessary in order to force the rest of the circuit to comply with its current source requirement. So the voltage across it is a "compliance voltage" that is needed here. We don't know what it is and because we don't, we can't actually calculate a sum of voltages around the loop without noticing this fact.

(The voltage across the current source might be \$0\:\textrm{V}\$ or it might be something else, entirely. We just don't know. So it must become a variable.)

Calling out \$V_Y\$ does allows us to now produce the equations for \$\ref{loop1}\$ and \$\ref{loop2}\$, finally. We also know \$\ref{given}\$, by definition.

---

If you solve those simultaneously for \$V_Y\$, \$I_1\$, and \$I_2\$, you will have your answers. Mostly, I just wanted to point out the mistake you made in writing things up in the first place.

There are other approaches towards simplifying things. (For example, \$R_2\$ could be removed because it does not affect \$V_X\$. It only affects \$V_Y\$. Removing \$R_2\$ would cause \$V_Y=V_X\$, but it would not affect \$V_X\$.) But it's not necessary as the above shows you. You can use the method you've been taught to use without using shortcuts to get there.

In short, ***yes*** you can use KVL in the presence of current sources.

Comment: ok i will use computer schematics. So why do we have to remove the middle branch to use KVL, and why does your trick solve this problem? Is it because there is no current flowing through R2 because of the current source's huge resisitance?

Comment: @user132522 The whole point of my writing above was to show you that you do NOT have to remove the middle branch. You can actually work the problem just as you were trying to do. You just missed a detail. If you still imagine that I've removed the middle, then you didn't understand what I wrote. (Which is my problem, not yours. I need to get better at writing.)

Comment: No, I get it that I can do it without removing the middle branch. I am just not clear why having Vx and Vy allows you to do that.

Comment: @user132522 I didn't need \$V_X\$. I probably should take that one away. But you do need to know that \$V_Y\$ is an unknown. Look, there is some unknown voltage across the current source. You don't know what it is. So you can't just assume it is zero, though. And whatever it is, you must account for it. Doesn't that make sense? That you can't just assume here? It's voltage has to be some value that might range from minus infinity to plus infinity? (This is no different for a voltage source, where the current through it is also unknown, but is some value from minus infinity to plus infinity.)

Comment: @user132522 I added \$V_X\$ only because it helps me clarify some thoughts at the very bottom where I talk about that node.

Answer (score 1):

Note that (1) you must not use KVL for a loop that contains a current source and that (2) a resistor that is in series with a current source could be shorted as the current source itself has ideally infinite resistance. To find i1 and i2 just use KVL around the big loop and use the fact that i2+i3=i1. You have two equations and two unknowns.

Comment: I never know that! My professor never said cuurent source has infinite resistance.

Comment: So how much resistance does a voltage source/battery have

Comment: A battery has generally a series, non-zero resistance that increases as the battery discharges. However, in circuit analysis we usually set the internal resistance of the voltage source to zero so we don't care about it much.